# Is it possible to send data from one service to another?

Tags: angular

In my loginService i have this:

```
getUserData(): any { return this.userData; }
```

What i want is to get that in logsService:

```
data = this.getUserData();
return this.http.get('/api/logs' + data.user.email)
                               // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                                .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                                //...errors if any
                                .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

            }
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You want to call a service from another service? Is that your question?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You should inject service in constructor, in the same way as inject service to component, f.e.

```
@Injectable()
export class FirstService {

    constructor(
        private _secondService: SecondService
    ){}

}

@Injectable()
export class SecondService {

    constructor( ){}

}
```